# Does not exist any $x \in [0, 1]$ for which the sequence $f_{n}(x)$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

Does there exist a sequence of continuous functions $f_{n}: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ such that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty }\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}(x)dx = 0$$
but there does not exist any $x \in [0, 1]$ for which the sequence $f_{n}(x)$ converges?

Typewriter sequence is an example such type of sequence of function, but this is not a sequence of continuous function, I have no idea how to construct such type of sequence of function. Give some hints.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is some kind of oscillating

Comment: You can mollify functions in the typerwriter sequence a bit to make them continuous.

Comment: @SangchulLee: You could post that as an answer; there's not much more to say. (See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35479.)

Comment: A simple analogy of the typewriter sequence that would satisfy this is to use triangular functions instead of rectangular ones (or half-triangles at the endpoints so that they are not identically $f(x)=0$).

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to modify the construction of the typerwriter sequence a bit. For each integer $n \geq 0$ and $0 \leq k < 2^n$, choose a smooth function $g_{n,k}$ such that

$$ \mathbf{1}_{[k/2^n, (k+1)/2^n]}(x) \leq g_{n,k}(x) \leq \mathbf{1}_{[(k-1)/2^n, (k+2)/2^n]}(x). $$

Then we re-enumerate $(g_{n,k})$ in lexicographical order to obtain a 1-D array $(f_n)$, that is,

$$ (f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4, f_5, f_6, f_7, \ldots) = (g_{0,0}, g_{1,0}, g_{1,1}, g_{2,0}, g_{2,1}, g_{2,2}, g_{2,3}, \ldots) $$

Then $(f_n)$ is smooth, and $(f_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ attains both $0$ and $1$ infinitely often for each $x \in [0, 1]$. Moreover, it is clear that the integral of $f_n$ converges to $0$.